# Exception determining maxBSONObjectSize/connection refused because too many open connections using Mule Mongo Connector

Tags: mongodb, mule, mule-studio, mongo-java

I'm using the Mule Mongo Connector to make some operations in a Mongo DB. I have been using it for a while without having this issue, but now I have this exception after running for a while my flow in Mule:

```
31-ago-2013 23:33:13 com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector fetchMaxBsonObjectSize
ADVERTENCIA: Exception determining maxBSONObjectSize 
java.io.EOFException
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:48)
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:33)
at org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:28)
at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:40)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:127)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:92)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:145)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.runCommand(DBPort.java:156)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.fetchMaxBsonObjectSize(DBTCPConnector.java:467)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:446)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:145)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:137)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.update(DBApiLayer.java:353)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:165)
at org.mule.module.mongo.api.MongoClientImpl.updateObjects(MongoClientImpl.java:185)
at org.mule.module.mongo.MongoCloudConnector.updateObjects(MongoCloudConnector.java:327)
at org.mule.module.mongo.processors.UpdateObjectsMessageProcessor$1.process(UpdateObjectsMessageProcessor.java:178)
at org.mule.module.mongo.process.ProcessCallbackProcessInterceptor.execute(ProcessCallbackProcessInterceptor.java:18)
at org.mule.module.mongo.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:69)
at org.mule.module.mongo.process.ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessInterceptor.java:21)
at org.mule.module.mongo.process.RetryProcessInterceptor.execute(RetryProcessInterceptor.java:69)
at org.mule.module.mongo.connectivity.ManagedConnectionProcessTemplate.execute(ManagedConnectionProcessTemplate.java:35)
at org.mule.module.mongo.processors.UpdateObjectsMessageProcessor.process(UpdateObjectsMessageProcessor.java:164)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.doProcess(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:54)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.access$001(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:26)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper$1.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.process(InterceptingChainLifecycleWrapper.java:65)
at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.processEventWithProcessor(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:312)
at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.routeWithProcessors(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:302)
at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:202)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:95)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:70)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:106)
at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:122)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:192)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:185)
at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:184)
at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I have been having a look at the ./mongod shell and I ALWAYS have this error when I'm having more than 200 connections opened:

```
Sat Aug 31 23:33:13.417 [initandlisten] connection refused because too many open connections: 204
Sat Aug 31 23:33:13.420 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52761 #868 (205 connections now open)
```

I have no idea what is going on. If any other information is needed, I can add it without any problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a [connection leaking issue](https://github.com/mulesoft/mongo-connector/pull/30) affecting the mongo connector. It has recently being addressed and it will be part of the next release.